# Initialization lists and std::forward

Tags: c++, constructor, move, forward

Am I right in assuming that

```
class D { /* ... */ };

int f (const D & t) { return /* something calculated from t */; }

template<class T>
class C {
private:
    int m_i;
    T m_t;
    // or first m_t, then m_i -- careless order of declarations
public:
    template<class T_>
    C (T_ && t) : m_t (std::forward<T_> (t)), m_i (f (t)) {
    }
};

C<D> c (D ());
```

may lead to a bug since the value of `t` has been moved away when `f(t)` is called? Is there any way to avoid this problem apart from (i) using a factory function or (ii) introducing a dependency on the order in which `m_i` and `m_t` are declared?

Comment: What's wrong with reordering the declarations and using `f(m_t)`? That seems to be the only thing that makes sense, too (think of explicit constructors for `T`).

Comment: I thought it's considered bad style and error-prone?

Comment: Well, you need what you need. *Programming* is error-prone, if you will. I don't like this design at all (what's with the strange relationship between `f` and `T_`?), but if that's what you need, you have to do it...

Comment: If you (i) want to cache some "property" (in the non-technical sense) of a member and (ii) want to make use of move semantics where possible, the design does not seem completely off to me. The problem remains if you don't have templates, but a constructor defined as `C (D && d) : m_t (std::move (d)), m_i (f(d)) {}`, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is that the order of evaluation of the initializer list is determined by the order of the members in the class definition, so in your case, it will be:

```
template<class T_>
C (T_ && t) 
  : m_i (f (t)), m_t (std::forward<T_> (t)) {
}
```

So in your case it is fine. It would also be fine if you reordered the members so that `m_t` is declared **before** `m_i` and you used `m_t` in the initialization:

```
T m_t;
int m_i;
template<class T_>
C (T_ && t) 
  : m_t (std::forward<T_> (t)), m_i (f (m_t))  {
}
```

Comment: Isn't that bad programming style?

Comment: @JohnB: I would surely add a comment on the variable definition to make sure they are not reordered. In general it is better to avoid the dependency on the order of evaluation, but in this case the dependency is already there, initialization of one member depends on the evaluation or not of the other as `std::forward` can cause the value to *move*.

Comment: I was going to write something like this, too, but then it struck me that your solution requires `T` to be convertible to `D`, while the original one only required `T_` to be thus. So they're subtly different. Though I don't claim to understand the design.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You can choose one or another. In the first case (i.e. without any change from the original code) the requirements are exactly the same --obviously. In the second case, as you mention, there are some differences regarding conversions. It is up to the user to determine which is the best option in their case.

Comment: If the constructor were `C (T && t) ...`, as it originally was, then we could not construct from an lvalue, I think, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @JohnB: I believe you are wrong. When used with the template argument the `&&` syntax is an *universal* reference. It will be either `T&` or `T&&` depending on the argument to the constructor.

Comment: Only if it's a template argument of the *function* (i.e. if the function/constructor is a template itself), I believe. I don't know about the spec, but it does not work with Visual Studio 2010 and `T` being a template type parameter of the *class*.

Comment: @JohnB: Right, it must be a template argument of the function. *Universal references* apply only to type deduction, and that only happens in function arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The member `m_i` is initialized first and by the time the value is clearly not moved nor will it be moved. When you initialize `m_t(std::forward<T>(t))` you implicitly promise that you won't use `t`s value (at least, until you have given it a new one).

In general, the order of execution matters and this is true for the member initializer list, too. That is, you need to be careful in which order you declare your members when you introduce dependencies between them.

Comment: Sorry, of course the idea was having the member declarations the other way round, in order to introduce a potential bug.